# error when using std::copy

Tags: c++, std

Hey guys I'm having trouble with some code I'm writing for a .obj model parser.
Here's the code that's causing the problem:

```
std::istringstream iss(line.substr(1));

std::copy(   
std::istream_iterator<float>(iss),     
std::istream_iterator<float>(),    
std::back_inserter<std::vector<float>>(model.chunks.back().vectices)  
);
```

It's basically taking a string passed as a argument like this:

> v -5.000000 -1.000000 1.000000

Then gets the substring from it so it's left with only this:

> -5.000000 -1.000000 1.000000

Finally I use std::copy and get each set of numbers from within the string:

> vertices[0] = -5.000000
>   vertices[1] = -1.000000
>   vertices[2] = 1.000000

Anyways the main problem here is that I'm getting an error from this line of code:

```
std::back_inserter<std::vector<float>>(model.chunks.back().vectices));
```

It says "expected token ';' got float" my code still compiles and run's flawlessly though.

Although if I replace the floats in that code with std::string's I don't get the error anymore.

```
std::copy(  
std::istream_iterator<std::string>(iss),   
std::istream_iterator<std::string>(),   
std::back_inserter<std::vector<std::string>>(model.chunks.back().vectices)  
);
```

I'm using Qt Creator so could this possibly be just a IDE error? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: std::back_inserter can deduce type from argument.

Comment: Why don't you just write `std::back_inserter(model.chunks.back().vectices)` and let the compiler deduce the type argument?

Comment: Hmm.. didn't think of that. It also requires less code. Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It might be that your IDE doesn't understand the `>>` in your template specification. Older versions of the C++ standard required that you put a space in between each `>` as in `> >`, otherwise it could be confused with the right shift operator `>>`. So:

```
std::back_inserter<std::vector<float> >(model.chunks.back().vectices));
```

Comment: Good theory, but he says it works with `std::string` in the last section of code, which includes the same `>>` sequence without spaces.

Comment: Ah, true. Curious that. But surely it's an IDE-specific thing, because otherwise code with syntax errors can't "compile and run flawlessly".

Comment: Just added a space in between the >> and the error went away! Must of been the IDE. Thanks you guys, and thank you for replying so quickly!